# Unable to receive data from serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, robotics

Currently I try to write a serial port communication in VC++ to transfer data from PC and robot via XBee transmitter. But after I wrote some commands to poll data from robot, I didn't receive anything from the robot (the output of filesize is 0 in the code.). Because my MATLAB interface works, so the problem should happen in the code not the hardware or communication. Would you please give me help?

01/03/2014 Updated: I have updated my codes. It still can not receive any data from my robot (the output of read is 0). When I use "cout<<&read" in the while loop, I obtain "0041F01C1". I also don't know how to define the size of buffer, because I don't know the size of data I will receive. In the codes, I just give it a random size like 103. Please help me.

```
// This is the main DLL file.
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //for GetCommState command
#include "Windows.h"
#include <WinBase.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){


  char init[]="";

  HANDLE serialHandle;

  // Open serial port
  serialHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM8", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

// Do some basic settings
  DCB serialParams;
  DWORD read, written;
  serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);

  if((GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams)==0))
  {
    printf("Get configuration port has a problem.");
    return FALSE;
   }

   GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams);
   serialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
   serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
   serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
   serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

   //set flow control="hardware"
   serialParams.fOutX=false;
   serialParams.fInX=false;
   serialParams.fOutxCtsFlow=true;
   serialParams.fOutxDsrFlow=true;
   serialParams.fDsrSensitivity=true;
   serialParams.fRtsControl=RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
   serialParams.fDtrControl=DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;

   if (!SetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams))
   {
       printf("Set configuration port has a problem.");
       return FALSE;

   }


   GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams);

   // Set timeouts
   COMMTIMEOUTS timeout = { 0 };
   timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 30;
   timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 30;
   timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 30;
   timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 30;
   timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 30;

   SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeout);

   if (!SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeout))
   {
       printf("Set configuration port has a problem.");
       return FALSE;

   }



   //write packet to poll data from robot
   WriteFile(serialHandle,">*>p4",strlen(">*>p4"),&written,NULL);



   //check whether the data can be received
   char buffer[103];



   do {
  ReadFile (serialHandle,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&read,NULL);
      cout << read;
    } while (read!=0);

     //buffer[read]="\0";



   CloseHandle(serialHandle);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work without the XBee, directly over serial?

Comment: sizeof( init ) will be 0 or 1 if the NULL is included.  The first WriteFile() will send no data.  Is this the problem you are having?

Comment: @Lokno Thanks for reply. Currently I don't have suitable cable to directly connect robot and PC serial... It may take me a little time to answer your question.

Comment: @TimDave My problem is that I can not receive any data after I send command to poll data. Even I deleted the first WriteFile, I still can not receive any data. I have updated my codes in the post.

Answer (score 1):

GetFileSize is documented not to be valid when used with a serial port  handle. Use the ReadFile function to receive serial port data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please instruct me how to set the size of data I will receive when using ReadFile? For example  I can write ReadFile(serialHandle, output, sizeof(output), &read, NULL); but I don't know how to define the size of "output". @Scott

Comment: You must pass ReadFile the size of the output buffer. That is the maximum number of bytes it will give you. But you cannot set the size of the data you will receive. That depends on device timing and the read timeout you have set. Check the &read parameter to find out how many bytes you actually got.

Comment: Hi @Scott, I have updated my codes in the post. It still can not work. The output of read give me 0. The output of &read give me "0041F01C1". What it means?

Comment: If ReadFile returns 0 then call GetLastError to find out why it failed.

Comment: Hi @Scott, When I used DWORD err = GetLastError(); output of err is always 0. But When I used error=ReadFile(serialHandle,LPVOID(buffer),255,&numberOfBytesRead,NULL); output of error is always 1.

Comment: If ReadFile returns 1 then it "worked". But "worked" includes returning numberOfBytesRead = 0 if there is a read timeout. A lot of things could go wrong here. Why not try it with no timeouts and no hardware handshakes just to see if you can get it to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` here:

```
WriteFile(serialHandle,init,strlen(init),&written,NULL)
```

You would be even better off creating a function like this:

```
function write_to_robot (const char * msg)
{
   DWORD written;
   BOOL ok = WriteFile(serialHandle, msg, strlen(msg), &written, NULL)
      && (written == strlen(msg));
   if (!ok) printf ("Could not send message '%s' to robot\n", msg);
}
```

But that's only the appetizer. The main trouble is, as MDN says:

*You cannot use the **GetFileSize** function with a handle of a nonseeking device such as a pipe or a communications device.*

If you want to read from the port, you can simply use `ReadFile` until it returns zero bytes.

If you already know the max size of your robot's response, try reading that many characters.
Continue reading until the read reports an actual number of bytes read inferior to the size of the buffer. For instance:

```
#define MAX_ROBOT_ANSWER_LENGTH 1000 /* bytes */
const char * read_robot_response ()
{
    static char buffer[MAX_ROBOT_ANSWER_LENGTH];
    DWORD read;
    if (!ReadFile (serialHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL))
    {
        printf ("something wrong with the com port handle");
        exit (-1);
    }
    if (read == sizeof(buffer))
    {
        // the robot response is bigger than it should
        printf ("this robot is overly talkative. Flushing input\n");

        // read the rest of the input so that the next answer will not be
        // polluted by leftovers of the previous one.
        do {
           ReadFile (serialHandle, buffer,  sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        } while (read != 0);

        // report error
        return "error: robot response exceeds maximal length";
    }
    else
    {
        // add a terminator to string in case Mr Robot forgot to provide one
        buffer[read] = '\0';

        printf ("Mr Robot said '%s'\n", buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

This simplistic function returns a static variable, which will be overwritten each time you call read_robot_response.

Of course the proper way of doing things would be to use blocking I/Os instead of waiting one second and praying for the robot to answer in time, but that would require a lot more effort.

If you feel adventurous, you can use overlapped I/O, as [this lenghty MDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx) thoroughly explores.

EDIT: after looking at your code

```
// this reads at most 103 bytes of the answer, and does not display them

if (!ReadFile(serialHandle,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&read,NULL))
   {
  printf("Reading data to port has a problem.");
  return FALSE;
    }

// this could display the length of the remaining of the answer,
// provided it is more than 103 bytes long

   do {
  ReadFile (serialHandle,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&read,NULL);
      cout << read;
    }
while (read!=0);
```

You are displaying nothing but the length of the response beyond the first 103 characters received.

This should do the trick:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN 1000
DWORD read;
char buffer [BUFFER_LEN];
do {
    if (!ReadFile(
        serialHandle,  // handle
        buffer,        // where to put your characters
        sizeof(buffer) // max nr of chars to read
             -1,       // leave space for terminator character
        &read, // get the number of bytes actually read
        NULL)) // Yet another blody stupid Microsoft parameter
    {
        // die if something went wrong
        printf("Reading data to port has a problem.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // add a terminator after last character read,
    // so as to have a null terminated C string to display
    buffer[read] = '\0';

    // display what you actually read
    cout << buffer;
}
while (read!=0);
```

I advised you to wrap the actual calls to serial port accesses inside simpler functions for a reason.
As I said before, Microsoft interfaces are a disaster. They are verbose, cumbersome and only moderately consistent. Using them directly leads to awkward and obfuscated code.

Here, for instance, you seem to have gotten confused between `read` and `buffer`

- read holds the number of bytes actually read from the serial port
- buffer holds the actual data.

`buffer` is what you will want to display to see what the robot answered you

Also, you should have a documentation for your robot stating which kind of answers you are supposed to expect. It would help to know how they are formatted, for instance whether they are null-terminated strings or not. That could dispense to add the string terminator.

Comment: Hi @kuroi, when I use buffer[read] = '\0'; the system give me the error "interface_test.cpp(100): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char' ". I have updated my codes in the pose. I guess the problem that I don't know the max size of my robot's response. Would you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to declare the `read` variable. The code was meant as a general principle illustration off the top of my head, not a fully working program.